# Writing uncompressed AVI video

Tags: c++, video

Is there any simple and small library or code sample to write uncompressed avi video files in c++?
Every resource I find uses video for windows, and I need this to be portable.

I tried looking at the AVI container documentation but it looks really cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it myself but I suggest using `libavformat`, part of `ffmpeg` (LGPLv2.1/GPLv2+).

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that is super easy, then write the BMPs to disk as a numbered sequence, then invoke `ffmpeg` via `system()` or something similar like this:

```
ffmpeg -i picture_%04d.bmp -r 15 -vcodec rawvideo -y output.avi
```

Note: the `-r` argument indicates the frame rate you want the final movie to be.

You could achieve the same result by calling into the libavformat/libavcodec libs that ffmpeg is based on, but that may not fit the "small" and "simple" requirement you have.

Comment: Performance-wise this results in a massive loss due to having to read/write files. In typical applications, file I/O outweighs the cost of any algorithmic processing.

Answer (score 0):

There is always [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/), which is multiplatform and relatively easy to push data into.

OR - you can always pipe the video data to another executable.

For instance, in unix you can do:

In your program:

```
char myimage[640*480*4];
// read data into myimage
fputs(myimage,1,640*480*4,stdout);
```

And in a script that runs your program:

```
./myprogram | \
mencoder /dev/stdin -demuxer rawvideo -rawvideo w=640:h=480:fps=30:format=rgba \
-ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4:vbitrate=9000000 \
-oac copy -o output.avi
```

(Note that this does compress the video - uncompressed is just a matter of changing the mencoder command-line)

I believe you can also use ffmpeg this way, or x264. You can also start the encoder from within your program, and write to a pipe (making the whole process as simple if you were using a library) - and this should work on Windows, Linux or Mac (with minor modifications to the mencoder command-line).

Obviously there are no licensing issues either (apart from distribution of the mencoder executable), as you are not linking to any code or compiling anything in.

While not quite what you want, it does have the advantage that a second processor will automatically be used for the encoding.